# Is there a way to make text on a button centered at the top?

Tags: html

I want to center my text at the top of my button but I can't find a way to do it.

I tried doing this:

```html
<a href="flappy">
    <button class="zoom" id="yes" style="width: 140px; height: 120px; border-radius: 20px; border-width: 0; font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; font-size: 20px; background-image: url(/images/flappy.jpeg); background-size: 100%;"></button>
    <div style = "color: #111; position: absolute; bottom: 5px; display: flex; justify-content: center;">Flappy Bird</div>
</a>
```

But it did not work.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding about how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards, please [edit] your question to add *all* the relevant code.

Comment: Buttons in anchors are invalid HTML

Comment: Also, I'd recommend using classes to keep your HTML readable.

Answer (score 0):

Inline styles

```html
<a
  style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center; text-decoration: none; width: 140px; height: 120px;"
  href="flappy">
  <span style="color: #111; margin-bottom: 5px">Flappy Bird</span>
  <button
    class="zoom"
    id="yes"
    style="width: 140px; height: 120px; border-radius: 20px; border-width: 0; font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; font-size: 20px; background-image: url(/images/flappy.jpeg); background-size: 100%;">
  </button>
</a>
```

With CSS

```css
  .link {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 140px;
    height: 120px;
  }
  .text {
    color: #111;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
  .button {
    width: 140px;
    height: 120px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border-width: 0;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-image: url(/images/flappy.jpeg);
    background-size: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<a class="link" href="flappy">
  <span class="text">Flappy Bird</span>
  <button class="zoom button" id="yes"></button>
</a>
```